# How to make `bpy.context.window.workspace = bpy.data.workspaces['Shading']` work in an unattended script?

Tags: python

I would like to switch to the Shading workspace in a script that is executed by calling blender with the `--python` argument.
For that purpose i have `bpy.context.window.workspace = bpy.data.workspaces['Shading']` in my script before doing all the other things.
Results of that other things are visible at next opening of the blend file. But the workspace keeps being Layout.
It works in the script window, but is completely ignored when running Blender exclusively for the script - with and without the `--background` option.
The ignorance goes so far, that `print(bpy.context.window.workspace)` right after setting the workspace returns the old workspace.

So how can the correct workspace actually be set by an unattended script so that the human can start working on the results right after opening the blend file without first having to switch the workspace himself?

---

Found a hacky solution implementing Marty Fouts' comment:

```
import threading
import time
import bpy

def main():
    # Do the actual work here as usual.

    threading.Timer(0.0, afterWork).start()

def afterWork():
    try:
        workspace = bpy.data.workspaces['Shading']
        window = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0]
        for _ in range(0, int(100.0/0.1)):
            window.workspace = bpy.data.workspaces[name]                        
            if window.workspace == workspace:
                break
            time.sleep(0.1)

        bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()

main()
```

It only works without the `--background` option and Blender crashes on `bpy.ops.wm.quit_blender()` but `bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()` works fine - so nothing is lost.

I'll use this hack until the real answer emerges...

Comment: Blender runs scripts given in the command line before it initializes the workspace.  So your initialization is being undone by Blender later.  The usual workaround is to add a timer at the start of the script so that Blender has enough time to initialize before your script actually runs.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want change to **"Shading"** workspace after open a blend file?

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def run_when_new_blend_file_open(dummy):
    try:
        print(" to 'Shading' workspaces ")
        bpy.context.window.workspace = bpy.data.workspaces['Shading']
    except:
        print(" can't find 'Shading' workspace")


bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(run_when_new_blend_file_open)
```

Comment: Tried this and the @persistent function gets never called. Might be because the blend file is already open when the script runs as the script is supposed to alter it. I can get it to run as save_pre - but then the workspace change is ignored.